# Discord Bot - limit to one reaction

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently working on discord bot and faced a problem where I need to limit reactions. I am trying to achieve the following goal - if the user selects reaction it should be replaced with the newest reaction. Can someone advise on how to do it?

Here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meMkT.png) and code of what I have at this moment.

**My code:**

```
client.on('raw', event => {
  console.log(event);
  const eventName = event.t;
  if(eventName === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
    if(event.d.message_id === '70цw3748527414706191') {
      var reactionChannel = client.channels.get(event.d.channel_id);
      if(reactionChannel.messages.has(event.d.message_id))
      return;
      else {
        reactionChannel.fetchMessage(event.d.message_id)
        .then(msg => {
          var msgReaction = msg.reactions.get(event.d.emoji.name + ":" + event.d.emoji.id);
          var user = client.users.get(event.d.user_id);
          client.emit('messageReactionAdd', msgReation, user);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
  }
  else if(eventName === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
    if(event.d.message_id === '703748527414706191') {
      var reactionChannel = client.channels.get(event.d.channel_id);
      if(reactionChannel.messages.has(event.d.message_id))
      return;
      else {
        reactionChannel.fetchMessage(event.d.message_id)
        .then(msg => {
          var msgReaction = msg.reactions.get(event.d.emoji.name + ":" + event.d.emoji.id);
          var user = client.users.get(event.d.user_id);
          client.emit('messageReactionRemove', msgReation, user);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
  }
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {

  var roleName = messageReaction.emoji.name;
  console.log(roleName);
  var role = messageReaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() ===
  roleName.toLowerCase());

  if(role) {
    var member = messageReaction.message.guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);
    if(member) {
      member.addRole(role.id);
      console.log("Success");
    }
  }
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (messageReaction, user) => {
  var roleName = messageReaction.emoji.name;
  var role = messageReaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() ===
  roleName.toLowerCase());

  if(role) {
    var member = messageReaction.message.guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);
    if(member) {
      member.removeRole(role.id);
      console.log("Success");
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check on messageReactionAdd, if they already have another color-role, with this you would need either each color role to have a prefix or to have an array of what color-roles exist.

heres a start

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    const guild = reaction.message.guild;
    const roleName = reaction.emoji.name.toLowerCase();
    console.log(roleName);
    const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() === roleName);

    if (role) {
        const member = guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === user.id);

        //check if they already have a color role
        if (alreadyColorRole) {
            //either make it so he cant react until he unreacts to the role
            //or automatically remove the other reaction.
            reaction.remove();
        } else {
            member.addRole(role.id);
            console.log("Success");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: doesnt work :( do not really have something else to write

Comment: What part of it didn't work? That code isn't the full part, you have to add your own variable to see if they already have a color role. Read the comments inside the code